# Is it posible to use VAST with a dynamically created video tag?

Tags: javascript, vast

I'm trying to make a video ad that opens and closes when the add is finished, instead of before or after a video (the common behavoir).

The problem is that as there is no real video before which to play the ad, I'd like to create it dinamicaly with JS.

Do you know if this is posible or does VAST throw an error if there is no real video from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do, it'd be great if you could clarify it a bit more.

You'll definitely need to use VPAID for something like this. You cannot execute JavaScript on a video player without using the JavaScript-based VPAID APIs. The video player will need to support VAST and JavaScript VPAID. Take a look at page 44 of the [VPAID spec](http://www.iab.net/media/file/VPAID_2.0_Final_04-10-2012.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1 pixel or blank video. Even you can trigger event to close video when ad gets complete.